# how to get the right position of the current item?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I am using the method `instantiateItem()` but it doesn't give me the right position of the first and the last item which is an image, so how will I do to get the right position of the image to play the sound.

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {  
    ImageView view = new ImageView(activity);
    view.setImageResource(tableImages[position]);
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(activity,tableSound[position]);
    mp.start();
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view);
    return view;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to call `getCount()` and compare the result with `position` to detect first and last pages.